# Best way to explain sublicensable (through multiple tiers)?

Tags: copyright, contract-law

I'd like to find a succinct definition of what it means in a software license agreement, to make the license "sublicensable (through multiple tiers)".  Ideally this would be a definition that could be included in such an agreement to make it clear to a layperson what this phrase means.

How would you define "sublicensable (through multiple tiers)"?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

A license that provides that the owner of the copyright in a software gives other people (the **Licensees**) the authorization:

1. to make copies of the software;
2. to authorize other people (the ***Sub-Licensees***) to make copies of the software; **and**
3. to authorize the Sub-Licensees to, in turn, grant to other people the right to do 1, 2 and 3.*

I guess we could call this a recursively sub-licensable right! :)

Comment: If there is an extensive license accompanying this clause, it would be worth setting out explicitly that sub-licensees would be bound by all/select terms of the license. eg. 'to make copies of the software (subject to the full text of this license).'